# VSTS build for UWP app not producing a .appxupload file

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops

**Issue:** When building a UWP using the VSTS build service no `.appxupload` file for store submissions is created.

**What I did:** I created a build definition using the *Universal Windows App* template that contains 4 build steps. Apart from setting the repository to my external Git repository I didn't change anything.

After the build finishes I only have the `_Test` folder in my drop. No `.appxupload` file.

**What I tried so far:**

1. According to [Build your Universal Windows Plattform app](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/windows/universal) I have to add the `UapAppxPackageBuildMode` (set to `CI`) switch to the MSBuild arguments. I did it exactly as shown there. However, neither the `.appxupload` nor the `_Test` folder are created but the build step itself completes successfully. (Actually, the `AppxPackages` folder that is specified by default using the `AppxPackageDir` switch is missing, too)
2. I tried running the `Create App Packages...` option from within Visual Studio. This results in both, the `.appxupload` and `_Test` folder.
3. **[Update]** I found another switch to try at the MSBuild arguments which is `AppxPackageIsForStore` (set to `true`). This will generate the `_Test` folder but still not `.appxupload` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue. If don't use argument `/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=CI`, I could only get _Test folder. If add argument `/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=CI`, I'll get error message during Publish Artifact step:

```
Not found PathtoPublish: C:\a\1\b\AppxPackages
```

But I just tried argument `/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload`, it can generate both `_Test` folder and `.appxupload` file, you may have a try.

[image]

Comment: Right. I didn't mention this error but is a direct result of not having the AppxPackages folder at all.

Comment: Cool. Finally! :) This did the trick. The documentation linked in point 1 of my question should be updated accordingly.