# Visual Studio Team Services: Build universal app for the store

Tags: azure-devops

I want to build universal app for release on the store i.e. generating the `*.appxupload` (building the `*.appx` to deploy on my machine is fine; have to remove the default `/p:AppxBundle=Always` though and **cannot** build Win32: no matter what I do, it always builds ARM). But I cannot get it to work at all following [Microsoft's instructions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/windows/universal) i.e. adding `/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=CI`.

The system simply stops with

*Error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Release|x86" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.*

My project has obviously an `Release|x86` configuration. And it reports this while building ARM release. I tried changing `x86` to `Win32` but it then report

*APPX0502: File 'C:\a\1\s\AppName\BundleArtifacts\Win32.txt' not found. [C:\a\1\s\AppName\AppName.vcxproj]*

**EDIT**: Apparently, I have to manually set the `Project` to `Win32` for it to build x86 release. Previously, it was left blank (and the automatic build configuration generator also leaves it blank).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the argument to:

```
/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload
```

And then queue the build, you should get the appxupload file.
[image]

Refer to this link for details: [Windows Store app projects stopped generating the .appxupload file](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2016/01/08/windows-store-app-projects-stopped-generating-the-appxupload-file-after-installing-vs-2015-update-1/).

Similar question here: [VSTS build for UWP app not producing a .appxupload file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713237/vsts-build-for-uwp-app-not-producing-a-appxupload-file).